# Mapview showing wrong search results

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I'm using iOS MapView. Whenever I search for a place it is giving surprising wrong results.

If I search for 'Pizza Hut' it takes me to Japan. If I search for Lalbagh, it takes me to Patna in Bihar. For UB City it takes me to U.S.

Can you please help me?

Here's the code to search.

```
_geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
            [_geocoder geocodeAddressString:textField.text completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
                //Error checking
                [Utility hideProgressHUD];
                CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
                MKCoordinateRegion region;
                region.center = [(CLCircularRegion *)placemark.region center];
//                region.center.latitude = placemark.region.center.latitude;
//                region.center.longitude = placemark.region.center.longitude;
                MKCoordinateSpan span;
                double radius = [(CLCircularRegion *)placemark.region radius] / 1000; // convert to km

                NSLog(@"[searchBarSearchButtonClicked] Radius is %f", radius);
                span.latitudeDelta = radius / 112.0;

                region.span = span;

                [_mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
            }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
NSString *location = @"some address, state, and zip";
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
                [geocoder geocodeAddressString:location 
                     completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error){
                         if (placemarks && placemarks.count > 0) {
                             CLPlacemark *topResult = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
                             MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithPlacemark:topResult];

                             MKCoordinateRegion region = self.mapView.region;
                             region.center = placemark.region.center;
                             region.span.longitudeDelta /= 8.0;
                             region.span.latitudeDelta /= 8.0;

                             [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
                             [self.mapView addAnnotation:placemark];
                         }
                     }
                 ];
```

I used above code in one of my application which is working fine for me in iOS8.

Comment: May work, but we cannot ask the user to search in the same pattern. User will simply type a location. By the way, how many zip codes can anyone remember accurately?

Comment: In this case you can avoid giving the zip code and try using the street name or particular area, it will work for you but giving the zip code can help `geocoder` to find more accurate result.

Comment: Just think in end user's perspective. As a normal user, nobody will search with street name, state, country or whatever. He will simply search for a keyword. What if a user wants to search "Coffee Day". He will simply say Coffee Day. He'll not mention any street. The intention of the user is to search for Coffee Days which are near to his current location.